# Select a parallel node in xslt

Tags: xslt, xpath

Consider following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <base>
     <a>
            <b>
                <c>Text 1</c>
            </b>
        </a>
    </base>
    <base>
        <a>
            <b>
                <c>Text 2</c>
            </b>
        </a>
    </base>
</root>
```

and this xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="root/base[1]" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="base//*">
        <xsl:if test="text()">
            <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
            <!-- i need Text 2 here -->
        </xsl:if>            
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The original xml is much more nested an i don't know the exact structure. But there is a parallel node with the same structure. If my template is at //root/base[1]/a/b/c I want to reference //root/base[2]/a/b/c

However I only know that I am in some node below //root/base[1] and that there is the same node in //root/base[2].

Is there a possibility to accomplish this goal?

Comment: Can there be nested elements of the same name? Or will the name (e.g. `c`) suffice to determine e.g. `/root/base[2]//*[local-name() = local-name(current())]`?

Comment: Brilliant, but however there may be elements with the same name :-(

Comment: Which specific XSLT processor will you be using? And what exactly is your expected output here? Your attempt seems to suggest that each `base` contains only one text node at most.

Comment: @michael: the Processor is currently Saxon 6.5.5. but I don't want to use any specific code, because the processor might change on different platforms. The example is very simplified, in the original there are several nodes named 'text' in different levels.

my expected output would be "Text 1, Text 2" 
<xsl:value-of select="text()" />, <xsl:value-of select="calculated path to base[2]/.../c/text()" />

Comment: Ideally, you would use an extension function to dynamically evaluate a path built by combining "root/base[2]/]" with the path to the current node. -- I don't see any "nodes named 'text'" in your input - and your output format is still not clear. Perhaps you have oversimplified the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This stylesheet requires no extensions, and does not make any assumption on unique names; the boring part is to pass the correct "twin node" every time you call `xsl:apply-templates`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="root/base[1]">
            <xsl:with-param name="twin" select="root/base[2]"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:param name="twin"/>
        <xsl:if test="text()">
            <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
            <xsl:value-of select="$twin/text()"/>
        </xsl:if>            
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select=".">
                <xsl:with-param name="twin" select="$twin/*[$pos]"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution with using saxon:evaluate extension (http://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon7.9/extensions.html#evaluate)

You can also use dyn:evaluate if you are using xslt 1.0 processors (http://exslt.org/dyn/index.html):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
version="1.0">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="root/base[1]" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="base//*">
        <xsl:if test="text()">
            <xsl:variable name="path">
                <xsl:call-template name="constructPath">
                    <xsl:with-param name="node" select="."/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="rewritedPath" select="concat('/root/base[2]', substring($path, 11))"/>

            <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
            <xsl:value-of select="saxon:evaluate($rewritedPath)" />
        </xsl:if>            
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="constructPath">
        <xsl:param name="node"/>

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$node/parent::node()/name()">
                <xsl:call-template name="constructPath">
                    <xsl:with-param name="node" select="$node/parent::node()"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('/', $node/name())"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('/', $node/name())"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here we use recursive template "constructPath" to create string and process it in evaluate() function. This will select the exact node as in the parallel branch. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below. This code will work only if each base element has children with unique element name.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="1.0">
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="root/base[1]" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="base//*">
        <xsl:if test="text()">
            <xsl:variable name="name" select="name()"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
            <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::base/following-sibling::base[1]//*[name() = $name]" />
       </xsl:if>            
       <xsl:apply-templates />
   </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()" />
```

However you can use dyn:evaluate from exslt extension or saxon:eval

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately the element name is not unique.Its mostly .../xxx/text. But I check whether the last two nodes are unique - so that i can use the parents name too.

Comment: then you need to install extension (evaluate) to build xpath dynamically